# TCP slow start and congestion avoidance problems?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, packets, congestion-control

Having a little problem with a trace i'm examining. I know a connection is in slow start if the window size is increasing along with the amount of ACKs sent between each segment and that it will increase by the size of the ACk'd segment. However the beginning of my trace is showing numbers that do not add up (Screenshot below). What i do not know is how packet 6's window size was calculated as the maths does not add up with the previous window size and ACKs in-between. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Also i have no idea how to spot when slow start becomes congestion avoidance. Is there something that i can look out for in the trace?

Slow start seems to only go until packet 13 so should i just assume that congestion avoidance has taken over?

http://img10.imageshack.us/f/tcptrace.jpg/

Thanks for any help given! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence starting 'I know' is incorrect, hence your confusion. You are conflating the receive window advertised by the receiver and the congestion window maintained by the sender, which does not appear in packets and which *doubles* on each ACK during slow start. This is not the place to reiterate all of RFC 2001 but I suggest you take another look at it.

Comment: Very odd, found out i was muddling the windows up (only minutes ago) and googled "Congestion control in wireshark" and this was the 7th link of the search. Anyway thanks for clearing that up, i'll check out RFC 2001 to find the congestion window size.

Comment: Also found out that my trace is showing ".... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set". This happens in EVERY packet. Is there a way to find the congestion size?

Comment: The congestion window size does not appear in the packet, as I said above. You're not going to learn all about this from a forum. I suggest you take a look at Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* Volume 1.

Comment: Well to be honest, all im trying to do is find out where slow start begins and ends and where congestion avoidance takes over using a times-sequence graph (Stevens). I can see where slow begins but not where it ends or where congestion avoidance takes over. I've the section on slow start in the Stevens, TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1 book but all it does is define it rather than show where to spot it.

Comment: I would have thought that congestion avoidance would show up when the window starts reducing or the packet intervals start to increase again.